# Dual Boot computer can reach sites under Windows, but not under Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, internet, dhclient

I have a dual boot system: Win-10, and Ubuntu 20.04.
Under Windows, I can ping and get web service from everywhere.
Under Ubuntu, I get response from some site, but not others.
I boiled the problem down to Ping, and did a couple screen captures that show the behavior.

It's not a network issue. Windows can reach both :

[image]

Ubuntu can ping google, but not Xfce :

[image]

---

Under Windows:

`ipconfig /all`

```
DNS Servers             : 192.168.1.254
```

Under Ubuntu I see no IPV4 config at all:

```
rdenise@Rhoda:~$ nmcli device show wlp3s0 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0  
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi 
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <snip>  
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Periwinkle_5G  
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         <snip>
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         <snip>  
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         <snip>  
IP6.GATEWAY:                            <snip>
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = <snip>
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = <snip>  
rdenise@Rhoda:~$
```

I found instructions for configuring a DNS server under Xfce at: [medium.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8hUt.png)
...which led to no joy.

Any additional suggestion you have would be appreciated.

Comment: That's exactly the issue - under Windows you have both IPv4 and IPv6 address, so you can connect to all sites. In Ubuntu you don't have an IPv4 address, only IPv6, so you can connect only to sites that run IPv6. You need to investigate why you don't get IPv4 address in Ubuntu.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, thanks for posting the answer. Do you think this problem was caused by an initial bad configuration of the network connection? Did you use default configuration?

Comment: This was the default configuration of the device. Be aware that I am connecting to Ethernet by wireless. The wireless device was recognized, and configured by Ubuntu out of the box, but the IPV4 fields were not populated. 

I'm kind of out of my league here. I found a solution that works, but I do not have enough insight to tell you that it the best solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION!**

I discovered that invoking
`$> sudo dhclient`
would populate the IPV4 fields in the Network Manager.

Then I found guidance from [archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#DHCP_problems_with_dhclient) that suggested creating the file
`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf` with the content

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

Rebooting with this configuration file in place generates the IPV4 addresses.

JOY!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows install using different DNS servers than Ubuntu to resolve addresses?

You can check your DNS in Win10 by typing `ipconfig /all` at a command prompt and in Ubuntu: `nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS`

You can get your interface name through `ifconfig` in Ubuntu